# Android - Do Firebase User Auth Tokens Expire?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I decided to use `Volley` and go the RESTful route with `Firebase` since their listeners seem to hang when there's no internet connection. At least with Volley, it lets me know if a network request was not successful due to internet connection or not.

I need to know whether `FirebaseUser` auth tokens expire or not. In my app, I only allow Google and Facebook authentication, and I use the following code assuming that Firebase user auth token DO NOT expire:

```
private String authToken;

// Callbacks

public interface ApiCallbacks {
    public void onSuccess(JSONObject response);
    public void onError(String errorString);
}

private interface AuthTokenCallbacks {
    public void onAuthTokenSuccess();
    public void onAuthTokenError(String errorString);
}

// Request Helpers

private void getAuthToken(final AuthTokenCallbacks callbacks) {
    // Lazy instantiation
    if (authToken == null) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user == null) {
            callbacks.onAuthTokenError("Please log in");
        } else {
            user.getToken(false).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        authToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        callbacks.onAuthTokenSuccess();
                    } else {
                        callbacks.onAuthTokenError("Please log in");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        callbacks.onAuthTokenSuccess();
    }
}

public void sendGetRequestTo(final String endpoint, final HashMap<String, String> arguments, final RequestQueue requestQueue, final String tag, final ApiCallbacks callbacks) {
    // Only execute get request if we have an auth token
    getAuthToken(new AuthTokenCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthTokenSuccess() {
            final String requestUrl = getRequestUrlString(endpoint, arguments);
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    callbacks.onSuccess(response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    callbacks.onError(error.toString());
                }
            });
            request.setTag(tag);
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthTokenError(String errorString) {
            callbacks.onError("Please log in");
        }
    });
}
```

Is this the correct way of doing it? I just need to know if I'm going in the right direction because I don't want future problems with my auth tokens expiring (if they do).

***EDIT***

I forgot to mention that my `final String requestUrl = getRequestUrlString(endpoint, arguments);` method basically constructs the url request string with `auth=authTokenString` appended at the end of my url.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they do expire (*you can check out the expiration date at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)*). If you don't force a refresh (i.e. `user.getToken(false)`), the returned token will be updated only if it has expired. If you pass `true` to `getToken(...)`, a new token will be created which also involves the linked providers' token validation on the firebase servers (e.g. validating against Facebook whether the user still has his/her account linked). Note that the latter counts towards your daily token service quotas, so make sure you use it only when it's necessary.